# How to do UNION on a single table

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure why I'm getting the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

My table looks like the following:

```
+-------+--------+---------------+
| label |  Name  |    Budget     |
+-------+--------+---------------+
|     1 |    ABC |  Allocated    |
|     1 |    DEF |  NotAllocated |
|     0 |    XYZ |  Allocated    |
|     0 |    LMN |  Allocated    |
|     1 |    QRS |  NotAllocated |
+-------+--------+---------------+
```

I have a column called `Label` consisting of 1's and 0's.

1. Number of records where `label` is 1 = 10540
2. Number of records where `label` is 0 = 1546

I have many records for "1" so I want to undersample them to the "0" level

I'm trying to get 1600 records where `label` is 1 and 1546 records where `label` is 0.

I have tried the following but I'm getting an error. How to solve this issue?

```
SELECT TOP 1600 *
FROM myTable  
ORDER BY label ASC 

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 1546 * 
FROM myTable  
ORDER BY label DESC
```

Comment: When you tried GurV's answer, you've commented that you got the "same error" - but in fact you get *different* error messages. When asking people for help, giving *good* feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1600 * FROM myTable ORDER BY label ASC) t1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1546 * FROM myTable ORDER BY label DESC) t2
```

You get the error message on the `ORDER BY` with `UNION`. You can place the `ORDER BY` only after the `SELECT` statements of `UNION`. In your case this would not work because you are using different `ORDER BY` conditions. So you can solve this by "re-select" the results of your queries. You can find more information about this topic on the [Transact-SQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql#f-using-union-of-two-select-statements-with-order-by).

---

As @Zorkolot already mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47416587/3840840) you don't need a `ORDER BY` in case you only want to `ORDER BY` column `label` to get the rows with 0 or 1. So you can use the following too:

```
SELECT TOP 1600 * FROM myTable WHERE label = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1546 * FROM myTable WHERE label = 1
```

> **demo (*for both solutions*):** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9c21/4/1

---

**Another thought:**

If you want to get a maximum amout of rows per group (max. 1600 rows with `label = 1` and max. 1600 rows with `label = 0`, so in sum max. 3200 rows). You should use the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1600 * FROM myTable WHERE label = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1600 * FROM myTable WHERE label = 1
```

Comment: yes pointing out, why the error, is very helpful to avoid it in future

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to get 1600 records where label is 1 and 1546 records
>   where label is 0.

You could just say `WHERE label = #` instead of using order by.

```
SELECT TOP 1600 *
  FROM myTable  
 WHERE label = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 1546 * --you might not even need TOP here (there are only 1546)
  FROM myTable  
 WHERE label = 0
```